# Check if latitude, longitude coordinates fall in irregular area on google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have an arbitrarily shaped blob that sits on google maps[image: noise plot for Sydney]

Given a point with specific lat and lon coordinates, how can I determine whether that point sits within the irregular area? (It is easy enough checking with an area such as a rectangle. But how about an irregular shape?)

Comment: This is more of a math/geometry question, specifically point v polygon. The basic idea is to connect the point with a point that's definitely inside the polygon, then intersect the resulting line with every side. If the number of intersections is even, the point is inside the polygon.

Comment: What does the data for the polygon's borders look like? Is it latitude/longitude coordinates? Are you using (or open to using) the Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

Comment: @geocodezip Definitely open to using Google Maps. I only have visual data for the polygon's borders, so I am open to translating it in some way into (an approximate) Google Maps polygon. Would there be a way to draw the lines manually and 'save' them as a polygon I can use?